# Ordering q.all promises

Tags: asynchronous, promise, sequelize.js, q, async.js

I'm trying to insert an array of users into a sequelize database using q.all() and the create() function like so:

```
var users = [{
      provider: 'local',
      role: 'user',
      name: 'Test user 1',
      email: 'test@example.com',
      password: 'test',
      gender: 'f'
    }, {
      provider: 'local',
      role: 'admin',
      name: 'Test user 2',
      email: 'test2@example.com',
      password: 'admin',
      gender: 'm'
    }];

    var userIDs = [];

    return q.all([
      User.create(users[0]),
      User.create(users[1])
    ])
    .then(function(data) {

      async.eachSeries(data, function(newUser, cb) {

        userIDs.push(newUser.dataValues._id);
        cb();

      }, function() {

        console.log('finished populating users');
        deferred.resolve(userIDs);

      });

    })
    .catch(function(err) {

      console.log(err);

    });
```

This works and I can access the userID's later on, but unfortunately the users returned in `data` are not always created in the same order. How can I make it asynchronous so that Test user 1 is always created first, then once that is finished, test user 2 is created?

Thanks for any help

Comment: sequelize already ships with promises - no need to include Q.

Comment: Maybe I am confusing matters. Basically I want to do a bulkCreate, but I need the insertID of each user. If I simply use the async library and sequelize, I get warning messages: `Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it
`

Comment: Don't use the async library. Sequelize comes with bluebird promises which are much more powerful and modern. Also - read stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read through that. I also just found this post https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2630 which suggests using bulkCreate and then a findAll() to get the IDs